# How can I make two tables called history and data show the results of cancelled reservations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am working with a stored procedure to give me the cancelled reservations of a school project, so far I have this query that handles a history parameter but I don't want to use it anymore, I want it to show all the cancellations of the two tables trying to optimize it as much as I can.

```
@FECHAINI AS DATETIME,
    @FECHAFIN AS DATETIME,
    @USUARIO AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @HISTORIAL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @QUERY AS VARCHAR(MAX)
        
        SET @QUERY = 'SELECT
        CASE WHEN (garantiada = ''S'') THEN ''G'' ELSE '''' END AS garantiada,
        case when STATUSDA = ''R'' then ''Reserva-Conf'' when STATUSDA = ''E'' then ''Reserva-XConf'' when STATUSDA = ''L'' then ''Reserva-L.Espera'' when STATUSDA = ''C'' then ''Cancelada'' when STATUSDA = ''X'' then ''Cancelada(L,E)'' when STATUSDA = ''O'' then ''Check-In'' when STATUSDA = ''B'' then ''Bloqueada'' when STATUSDA = ''G'' then ''Grupos'' when STATUSDA = ''D'' then ''Check-out'' when STATUSDA = ''F'' then ''Check-Out Folio'' else STATUSDA end as STATUSDA,
        NUMRESDA,NOMBREDA,NUMPERDA, TARIFADA,
        SUBSTRING(cveestda1,2,LEN(cveestda1)) as cveestda1, 
        NUMCUADA, FHAENTDA, FHASALDA,
        SUBSTRING(cveestda14,2,LEN(cveestda14)) as pqte, 
        SUBSTRING(cveestda2,2,LEN(cveestda2)) as age, 
        SUBSTRING(cveestda4,2,LEN(cveestda4)) as seg, 
        SUBSTRING(cveestda5,2,LEN(cveestda5)) as pg, 
        SUBSTRING(cveestda6,2,LEN(cveestda6)) as cia, 
        NUMCANDA, DEPOSIDA,
        DATEDIFF(DAY,FhaEntda,FhaSalda) as Noches,
        FECHRESDA,PASEDA
        FROM '
        IF (@HISTORIAL = 'S')
            SET @QUERY += 'historial'
        IF (@HISTORIAL = 'N')
            SET @QUERY += 'datos'

        SET @QUERY += ' WHERE FECHRESDA BETWEEN '''+ CAST(@FECHAINI AS VARCHAR(MAX))+''' AND '''+CAST(@FECHAFIN AS VARCHAR(MAX))+''' '

        IF (@USUARIO <> '')
            SET @QUERY += 'and STATUSDA = ''C'' and PASEDA = '''+ @USUARIO +''' ORDER BY nombreda'
        ELSE
            SET @QUERY += 'and STATUSDA = ''C'' ORDER BY nombreda'

        PRINT(@QUERY)
    EXEC (@QUERY)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT  ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERRORMESSAGE;  
    END CATCH
END
```

This is what I have so far I have been making modifications but it does not work, I have already used union all and only the union for the tables but it does not work, it is worth mentioning that I am using this stored procedure for a report in Crystal Reports.

Comment: FYI, It's generally advised to not use syntax such as `EXEC (@SQL);`. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection; which your attempt *does* suffer from. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to.

Comment: Why do you define your parameter `@HISTORIAL` as likely to have more than 4,000 characters when it *appears* it'll only be one character in length? Also, as I mentioned, you are *injecting* your parameters. `@USUARIO` is also a `MAX` length, which means you are allowing someone **2GB** of characters to wreck havok on your instance. Depending on the permissions of the account that is connecting to the instance, they could *literally* do anything with that much injection scope.

Comment: Can you give some sample data and the expected output? Also simply stating it "does not work" doesn't give us enough to go off of. Check out [How to create Minimal Reproducable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've tried this yet, since there isn't any example code of what you've tried (and you did say you tried *something* with unions and it "didnt work") but as I understand it, you just need data from both tables now, ignoring the flag which switched the tables.

Here's how I'd do that. Note, I've refactored the dynamic sql to use `sp_executesql` (and removed all your select fields, since they're immaterial to the question at hand).

I've switched your `exec` calls to use [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
which has numerous advantages over `exec`, not least of which is the ability to parameterize dynamic sql, thus preventing the risk of injection attack (note, the code I've given below is safe from injection attack, but that's doesn't automatically happen just by using `sp_executesql`. If you plan to use dynamic sql, you should *really* get to understand how injection attacks work, and how to prevent them using things like `quotename`, `sp_executesql`, and parameterization.)

```
set @QUERY = concat
('
    select Field
    from
    (
        SELECT Field = ''datos''
        FROM datos
        where FECHRESDA BETWEEN @FECHAINI and @FECHAFIN
            and STATUSDA = ''C''
            ', iif(@USUARIO <> '', ' and PASEDA = @USUARIO', ''), '
        union 
        select ''historial''
        from historial
        where FECHRESDA BETWEEN @FECHAINI and @FECHAFIN
            and STATUSDA = ''C''
            ', iif(@USUARIO <> '', ' and PASEDA = @USUARIO', ''), '
    ) a
    order by nombreda'
)
exec sp_executesql
    @QUERY,
    N'
        @FECHAINI datetime,
        @FECHAFIN datetime,
        @USUARIO varchar(max) -- probably shouldnt be varchar max
    ',
    @FECHAINI,
    @FECHAFIN,
    @USUARIO
```

I've used a `union` there instead of a `union all` because I'm not sure what your data is. If the same rows could exist in both tables, and you don't want duplicates, using `union` would be the way to go (at the cost of it having to do a distinct across the results). If you know both tables have mutually exclusive data sets, and there aren't duplicates you care about, you could also use `union all`. It's faster, because it doesn't make sure you have a single distinct dataset after the union operation.